# How to use C++ to implement SimilarityTransform in scikit-image without using estimateRigidTransform in OpenCV?

Tags: python, c++, image, opencv

When I try to translate a project written in python to C++. I have to implement the function SimilarityTransform in the package scikit-image. I find estimateRigidTransform in OpenCV will do the same thing. But estimateRigidTransform will return empty matrix somtimes. So, Is there some method that which will works better than that and alway return a matrix?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I found a function in eigen3, can do the same thing as the python code does.

Comment: can you link to that? or update your answer with the actual code snippet?

Comment: Why would you just say you found a function, but then not go ahead and specify which function. By doing that, this answer is very unhelpful.